# How to calculate the probability Matrix (Alpha) for Regular Markov chains

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model, transition-matrix, markov-decision-process

Pardon me for being a novice here. In the image attached, eq 3.1 represents the transition matrix (it's pretty clear). I am not able to comprehend the eq 3.2, alpha*P = alpha, as well as the further equations.

I have the P matrix with me as an outcome of one of my projects. How should I calculate alpha and the elements a1, a2, a3....etc?

I would request some of your valuable guidance and help.

Mritunjay

[image: An excerpt]

[image: 2nd page]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is my correct answer. I forgot to mention a negative sign on C2R1. Done!!
[image]

Comment: I'm happy that you managed to work it out. :)